# Autolayout issue for UITextField in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, autolayout

I created `UITextField` in storyboard. And added its constraints also. I want search icon on left side of UITextField. The code for adding search icon is as follows:

```
self.searchTextField.leftView = searchIconImage;
    self.searchTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    [self.searchTextField addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

My application is working fine on iOS8 and its crashing on iOS7. The error is as follows:

> Assertion failure in -[UITextField layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.138/UIView.m:8794
>   2014-11-05 12:54:33.377 WattUp[1722:60b]  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITextField's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'

Comment: See last statement in error. UITextField's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.' Did you subclass UITextfield?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 yes I subclass UITextField. My app is working fine on iOS8. The issue is only on iOS7.

Comment: Are you calling super as the comment says?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 thank you very much for your reply. I managed to resolve this issue bay calling loadSubViews on my UITextField. It's working on both iOS8 and iOS7.

Answer (score 8):

So I ran into this same error a few days ago as well. It turns out I was trying to layout subviews inside my `UITextfield` subclass, setting properties on them, moving them, etc, but was never explicitly telling the view to lay itself out (i.e. calling `[self layoutIfNeeded]`).

iOS 8 seems to force to a view to layout all its subviews, and then configures constraints on it. iOS 7 won't, and needs you to explicitly tell views to redraw their subviews when you change if you're using autolayout.

In my case, I had subclassed `UITextField` and added a label to the side. I configured the frame of the label by adding constraints to the UITextfield. One of the public methods I could call on my class was

```
- (void)setLabelText:(NSString *)newText{
    self.sideLabel.text = newText;
}
```

This caused my application to crash when a view controller appeared containing my subclassed textfield. By add `layoutIfNeeded` everything works fine in iOS7 and iOS8.

```
- (void)setLabelText:(NSString *)newText{
    self.sideLabel.text = newText;
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

This needs to be called every time you change a part of the view in your subclass. This includes the setup when you add subviews, when you change view properties, anything really. Before the function that's changing your view returns, call `layoutIfNeeded` on your view. This seems to apply for a few standard UI controls including UITextfield, UITableView and UICollectionView, though I'm sure there are others. I hope this was clear enough and helped solve your problem.

The error you're getting isn't super useful, and didn't even apply in my case. Though I was receiving the exact same error, none of my views implementing `layoutSubviews`, and thus were all using the `[super layoutSubviews]` method.

Comment: Thanks! This solved a really annoying problem I was having. Everything was working fine on iOS 8, but not working on iOS 7

Comment: Thank you! In my case, I had written a custom range slider and was getting the same error as that listed in the original question. I had overridden `layoutSubViews` to deal with repositioning of the slider thumbs during resizing. In my case, the error message was partially correct, as I had forgotten to call the super class in `layoutSubviews`. In addition to that, I needed your solution, which was to add `[self layoutIfNeeded]` after calls that repositioned the thumbs.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by subclassing UITextField and reimplementing 2 methods:

```
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text
{
    [super setText:text];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

really annoing thing. Apple makes programmers cry so often