# override UILabel setText: method in Swift

Tags: swift, ios7, uilabel

I do have the problem that I got some crashes in iOS with a `UILabel` subclass. Now I would like to override `setText:` to call `layoutIfNeeded` as this may solve the problem according to some stackoverflow-answers ([e.g. this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751801/autolayout-issue-for-uitextfield-in-ios%20e.g.)).

But how can I achieve this? In Objective-C it was no big deal, but I don't find a way to override `setText:` in Swift.

Answer (score 13):

Override the property `text` and provide code in `didSet` which will get executed when the `text` property is set:

```
class MyLabel: UILabel {
     override public var text: String? {
        didSet {
            layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct answer here. Beat me to this by a minute. :)

Comment: @DanRosenstark did you changed your uilabel to custom uilabel on both interface builder and on the swift class. Via this way I can override set text method.

Answer (score 3):

**I pulled of Method Swizzling in Swift 2.0. Over riding the setText method of UILabel.**

*Copy the code in app delegate and use the customSetText to make application level changes*

```
   // MARK: - Method Swizzling

extension UILabel {
    public override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        // make sure this isn't a subclass
        if self !== UILabel.self {
            return
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            let originalSelector = Selector("setText:")
            let swizzledSelector = Selector("customSetText:")

            let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
            let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)

            let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))

            if didAddMethod {
                class_replaceMethod(self, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
            } else {
                method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Custom set text method for UI Label

    func customSetText(text: String) {
        self.customSetText(text)
        //set custom font to all the labels maintaining the size UILabel
        self.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-LightItalic", size: self.font.pointSize)
    }
}
```

Comment: swift 4 does not support `public override class func initialize()` anymore and throws this error : **Method 'initialize()' defines Objective-C class method 'initialize', which is not permitted by Swift**, any idea how to convert the above code block to swift 4 version ?